# E-mail hyperlinks: reading href value

Tags: email, hyperlink, com, outlook, vsto

So when you click on an email hyperlink, it opens up a new mail message window in the default mail client (Outlook in my case). You can append Subject, Body, CC and BCC fields directly to the email hyperlink and your mail client will automatically populate those values in the corresponding boxes. An example hyperlink field would be:

```
<a href="mailto:someone@example.com?Subject=Hello%20again">Send Mail</a>
```

So here we go. User clicks the hyperlink and a new inspector window is opened by Outlook. I'm listening to `NewInspector` event in my Outlook add-in. Can I somehow get the full href of the link that was clicked to bring up this inspector window?

The reason I want this is that I'm appending some custom fields to the hyperlink, which obviously are not understood by Outlook. Can I get the entire href value through some direct property, or COM?

Answer (score 0):

No, the Outlook object model (nor the mailto: protocol) doesn't provide anything for that. Instead, you can automate Outlook to fill the required values programmatically. For example, if Outlook is already running you can use the following code:

```
  // If so, use the GetActiveObject method to obtain the process and cast it to an Application object.
  application = Marshal.GetActiveObject("Outlook.Application") as Outlook.Application;
```

Read more about that in the [How to: Get and Log On to an Instance of Outlook](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff462097.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) article. Also you may find the [C# app automates Outlook (CSAutomateOutlook)](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/CSAutomateOutlook-a3b7bdc9) sample project helpful.

Comment: Not sure if you understood the question properly. I don't need to get a handle of Outlook application; I already have that. Add-ins run as in-process modules and thus I can easily get reference to the application object. The problem here is that by the time `NewInspector` event is raised, (I think) Outlook has already parsed the href and populated corresponding fields, ignoring any parts that it doesn't know about. My only hope here is the Outlook stores the original href somewhere in the COM properties.

Comment: Nope. You have no control over that. As I said, you can automate Outlook from another application to populate fields programmatically or just communicate with your add-in using standard .net mechanisms such as .Net remoting.